# В чем ошибка: "В красивых, одетых в бренды в парижских женщин"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

**Предложение из текста:**

...которые так напоминают места из культовых фильмов. *В красивых, одетых в бренды в парижских женщин*.

Comment: Я думаю что в предложении "В красивых, одетых в бренды в парижских женщин." есть ошибка, но какая - мне не ясно точно.

Answer (score 1):

Грамматически - здесь лишний третий предлог "в" (судя по контексту, не нужен и первый предлог). С точки зрения культуры речи, нельзя "*одеваться в бренды*"; можно носить *одежду* "известных брендов" ("бренды", или по-старосоветски "марки" продукции бывают уважаемые и не очень: "Рога и копыта" - тоже бренд). Поэтому здесь если не просторечие, то рекламный штамп (вспомните неуклюжий затасканный слоган "бренды - даром").